# Clean Installation with manual partitioning

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I have a PC with a Fusion Drive(128 GB SSD and 1TB HDD). On my PC, `/home` folder is also in SSD. So my SSD will fill up soon and HDD will stay blank , thus I decided to re-install ubuntu with manual partition so that I can put `/home` folder in HDD.

But how can I wipe my previous Ubuntu installation during installing a fresh copy of Ubuntu with manual partitioning??

Comment: You could try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk).

Comment: You do have good backups? Including /home, all data, & list of installed apps. And if any server apps installed those folders in / (root)? Some alternatives are move /home or create data partition(s) for your data in /home. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving  Move data & link folders back into /home. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are in the manual partitioning section of the installer there is a checkmark "wipe" or "format " in options for creating or assigning a `/home` partition

The other option is if you delete all existing partitions and create brand new ones. That will wipe all data. (also from within the installer). There is a warning before you proceed that tells you exactly what will be wiped.